# CSS3 family tree, how to add wife

Tags: html, css, family-tree

I'm following this [guide](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) on how to make a family tree using only CSS3. But I can't really get my head around how to make a marriage.

To clarify:
What the codes does now is this:
[image]

what i want to add is this:
[image]

I know it's a simple question, but right now im stock

Comment: CSS is not designed as a diagramming language. SVG is much better suited to this task.

Comment: True, but right now my problem is getting this ul to work properly, then I will be able to change the style :D

Comment: I'm guessing the wife has to come from another tree.

Comment: Not necessarily. There is no need to see her ancestors, only her decendants

Comment: I'm with Quentin. HTML creates structure. CSS styles HTML.

Comment: Anyone who knows a good guide in SVG to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears someone has [updated](http://thecodeplayer.com/experiments/css3-family-tree-multiple-parents.html) the original code to support husband/wife relationships. Good luck!

Comment: Also take a look at the comments; some people really took the idea and ran with it.

Answer (score 3):

From the notes on the page:

"Note: I am working on a new version of this family tree which will have IE support to some extent and will have multiple parents to make it a practical solution for a family tree."

So it looks like 'multiple parents' aren't supported as yet.

Comment: if you are interested in genealogy, fyi there is an effort to start a genealogy stackexchange.Help it reach beta: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history?referrer=DIRpC-2QEpSJcDcQkP0RAg2  It needs more high score people with stackexchange experience (as opposed to newbies like myself)

Answer (score 3):

What about just putting husband/wife in same li element and then using CSS to connect them?  Something like this:

```
<style>
  .husband { float: left; }
  .wife { margin-left:10px; }
  .wife::before { 
    /* pseudo CSS, will need to be modified */
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
  }
</style>


<li>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="husband" href="#">Grand Child</a>
            <a class="wife" href="#">Wife</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Kid</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Kid</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the approach I took

```
<li>
  <ul>
    <li>Father</li>
    <li>Mother</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="http://www.clarkeology.com/names/clarke/21/james">James CLARKE1779 - 1860</a>
  <div itemprop="spouse">
    <a href="http://www.clarkeology.com/names/cole/19/elizabeth">Elizabeth COLE 1794 - 1865</a>
  </div>
  <ol>
    <li><a>Child</a></li>
    <li><a>Child</a></li>
    <li><a>Child</a></li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

then any `<li>` throughout the tree can repeat like that (though if you add children AND parents to all of them you'd get a mess... generally just add one or the other once you get past the "core" person in that view.

Real example is on http://www.clarkeology.com with annotated css at /css/_tree.css and the code I wrote to parse a GEDCOM file and create the necessary html is at https://github.com/pauly/js-gedcom

I used `itemprop` instead of `class` above as I'm actually adding schema.org microformats to all mine too, but class would work just fine.

I really enjoyed the original css when I found it the other day, this has been fun to work on. Pull requests welcome on my code!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<li>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Wife</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So wrap the last grand-child into a ul. This gives you a line over the two, not in between but I don't think your box model allows for this right now...

Comment: That would make the wife a sibling to the grand child. I need a way to get the wife "out of the system" and yet still connected to the husband

Comment: A yes of course, I see... Trouble is that the connecting line are placed on the bounding boxes of the elements. That isn't possible on that spot. I began fiddling with a span to connect the grandchild-wife but that killed the line connecting grandchild to child. Structurally this _is_ correct however. You would start a new `ul` to indicate a new tree. It's the current CSS that doesn't play well with this concept. Like Quentin said: CSS isn't really intended for this...