# CSS Family tree, How to go upwards in tree

Tags: html, css, tree

I'm making a family tree using only html and css using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051809/css3-family-tree-how-to-add-wife/23620012#23620012?newreg=64edf683671d45ec9c3694ef618efdbe)

Now i know how to make a married couple, but what if i want to know who the parents are from "wife"? So i want to go upwards in the tree instead of down.

To clarify (in blue): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjRUu.jpg)

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do this in CSS. But you can try something with flex order as a work around if you must use CSS

Comment: How can i use flex order? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

There are no parent selectors in css.

https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14854158)

Comment: @Joseph The answer is that it's not possible.